# In Apollo-client the writeQuery updates the cache but the UI components do not rerender

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have followed the documentation of Apollo client 2.6 to the letter. It seems that people online seem to be having this issue since 2018. Am I missing something? The docs should be updated, this just does not work and it is clear it does not work for so many people.

How do I get my UI to update when the cache is written to successfully. This should happen out of the box. It is a create mutation, I am adding a record in the `addleo` mutation after which I want to show the added record in the list of all records, which is `LIST LEOS`:

```
const ADD_LEO = gql`
mutation AddLeo($text: String!, $userId: String!){
  addLeo(text: $text, userId: $userId) {
    id
    text
    userId
  }  
}
`;

 const LISTLEOS = gql`
query LISTLEOS {
  ListLeos {
    id
    text
    userId
  }
}
`;

  const [addleo, { loading, error }] = useMutation
      (
          ADDLEO,
          {
            update(cache, {data: {addleo}}){
                const { ListLeos } = cache.readQuery({ query: LISTLEOS});
                cache.writeQuery({
                    query: LISTLEOS,
                    data: { ROOT_QUERY: ListLeos.concat([addleo])},
                }); 
            }
          } 
      );
```

The above should cause the components associated with `LISTLEOS` to rerender but it is not. Please help.

Comment: bad syntax/bad data provided ... start with making sure you're doing things right

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `ROOT_QUERY` as a key. The `data` option passed to `writeQuery` should look just like the `data` returned by your server:

```
cache.writeQuery({
  query: LISTLEOS,
  data: { ListLeos: ListLeos.concat([addleo])},
});
```